# Problema al mostrar Json en Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, http

Estoy intentando mostrar un Json que contiene una serie de preguntas con opciones (son 12 preguntas con 3 opciones cada una), de manera que en cada página quede algo así, tengo pensado en usar un PageView.

> Mi estado de ánimo es
>
> Por lo general es bastante positivo
>
> Últimamente me siento algo triste o melancólico
>
> Me causa un auténtico sufrimiento, pues me siento triste la mayor
> parte del día

Con lo que he hecho hasta el momento he conseguido que muestre un listado de las preguntas, pero no consigo que aparezcan las opciones.

**Estructura del Json:**

```
{
"id": 1,
"pregunta_set": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "opcion_set": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "color": "V",
                    "valor": 0.0
                },
                "nombre": "Por lo general es bastante positivo",
                "pregunta": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "color": "A",
                    "valor": 2.777777778
                },
                "nombre": "Últimamente me siento algo triste o melancólico",
                "pregunta": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "color": "R",
                    "valor": 5.555555556
                },
                "nombre": "Me causa un auténtico sufrimiento, pues me siento triste la mayor parte del día",
                "pregunta": 1
            }
        ],
        "nombre": "Mi estado de ánimo es:",
        "test": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "opcion_set": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "color": "A",
                    "valor": 2.777777778
                },
                "nombre": "No espero nada de ellos.",
                "pregunta": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "color": "V",
                    "valor": 0.0
                },
                "nombre": "Intento ser cauto, pero los miro con optimismo.",
                "pregunta": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "color": "R",
                    "valor": 5.555555556
                },
                "nombre": "Me siento algo desanimado respecto a cómo me van a ir las cosas.",
                "pregunta": 2
            }
        ],
        "nombre": "Respecto a mis planes de futuro:",
        "test": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "opcion_set": [
            {
                "id": 10,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "color": "V",
                    "valor": 0.0
                },
                "nombre": "A pesar de que no hayan podido cumplirse todos me siento bastante satisfecho.",
                "pregunta": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "color": "A",
                    "valor": 2.777777778
                },
                "nombre": "Pocas cosas de las que he hecho han merecido la pena.",
                "pregunta": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "color": "R",
                    "valor": 5.555555556
                },
                "nombre": "Me siento un auténtico fracasado como persona.",
                "pregunta": 3
            }
        ],
        "nombre": "Respecto a mis objetivos en la vida",
        "test": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "opcion_set": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "color": "V",
                    "valor": 0.0
                },
                "nombre": "Está lleno de anécdotas; unas buenas y otras malas.",
                "pregunta": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "color": "R",
                    "valor": 5.555555556
                },
                "nombre": "Me aburre muchísimo y nada me interesa.",
                "pregunta": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "color": "A",
                    "valor": 2.777777778
                },
                "nombre": "Últimamente despierta menos interés para mí.",
                "pregunta": 4
            }
        ],
        "nombre": "Mi día a día",
        "test": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "opcion_set": [
            {
                "id": 16,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "color": "V",
                    "valor": 0.0
                },
                "nombre": "No me arrepiento de cómo he actuado estos años. Si me he equivocado, ese error me valdrá para aprend",
                "pregunta": 5
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "color": "R",
                    "valor": 5.555555556
                },
                "nombre": "Me siento culpable por muchas cosas. No valgo nada.",
                "pregunta": 5
            },
            {
                "id": 18,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "color": "A",
                    "valor": 2.777777778
                },
                "nombre": "Estoy arrepentido de gran parte de las cosas que he hecho.",
                "pregunta": 5
            }
        ],
        "nombre": "Cuando miro hacia atrás y pienso en las decisiones que he tomado o en todo lo que he hecho",
        "test": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "opcion_set": [
            {
                "id": 19,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "color": "V",
                    "valor": 0.0
                },
                "nombre": "A veces gano yo. Otras ganan ellos.",
                "pregunta": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "color": "A",
                    "valor": 2.777777778
                },
                "nombre": "Siempre salgo mal parado; la mayoría de la gente es mejor que yo.",
                "pregunta": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "color": "R",
                    "valor": 5.555555556
                },
                "nombre": "Me doy asco.",
                "pregunta": 6
            }
        ],
        "nombre": "Cuando me comparo con otras personas",
        "test": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "opcion_set": [
            {
                "id": 22,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "color": "R",
                    "valor": 5.555555556
                },
                "nombre": "He llorado prácticamente todos los días.",
                "pregunta": 7
            },
            {
                "id": 23,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "color": "A",
                    "valor": 2.777777778
                },
                "nombre": "Lloro mucho más que antes; casi la mitad de los días.",
                "pregunta": 7
            },
            {
                "id": 24,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "color": "V",
                    "valor": 0.0
                },
                "nombre": "No he llorado sin ningún motivo aparente.",
                "pregunta": 7
            }
        ],
        "nombre": "En las dos últimas semanas",
        "test": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "opcion_set": [
            {
                "id": 25,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "color": "V",
                    "valor": 0.0
                },
                "nombre": "Mi interés hacia las mismas no ha sufrido ninguna variación.",
                "pregunta": 8
            },
            {
                "id": 26,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "color": "A",
                    "valor": 2.777777778
                },
                "nombre": "Me intereso por los demás, pero menos que antes.",
                "pregunta": 8
            },
            {
                "id": 27,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "color": "R",
                    "valor": 5.555555556
                },
                "nombre": "He perdido el interés por relacionarme con la gente. No me apetece.",
                "pregunta": 8
            }
        ],
        "nombre": "En lo que respecta a mis relaciones sociales",
        "test": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "opcion_set": [
            {
                "id": 28,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "color": "A",
                    "valor": 2.777777778
                },
                "nombre": "Me despierto antes o en mitad de la noche y me cuesta volver a dormirme.",
                "pregunta": 9
            },
            {
                "id": 29,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "color": "V",
                    "valor": 0.0
                },
                "nombre": "Duermo como siempre.",
                "pregunta": 9
            },
            {
                "id": 30,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "color": "R",
                    "valor": 5.555555556
                },
                "nombre": "Duermo mucho más que antes o no pego ojo.",
                "pregunta": 9
            }
        ],
        "nombre": "En lo que respecta a mis hábitos de sueño",
        "test": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "opcion_set": [
            {
                "id": 31,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "color": "R",
                    "valor": 5.555555556
                },
                "nombre": "No me apetece comer nada o no paro de comer.",
                "pregunta": 10
            },
            {
                "id": 32,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "color": "A",
                    "valor": 2.777777778
                },
                "nombre": "Ha variado un poco; como más o no como a penas.",
                "pregunta": 10
            },
            {
                "id": 33,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "color": "V",
                    "valor": 0.0
                },
                "nombre": "Es igual que siempre.",
                "pregunta": 10
            }
        ],
        "nombre": "Respecto a mi apetito",
        "test": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "opcion_set": [
            {
                "id": 34,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "color": "V",
                    "valor": 0.0
                },
                "nombre": "Las cosas me cunden como siempre; ni más ni menos.",
                "pregunta": 11
            },
            {
                "id": 35,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "color": "R",
                    "valor": 5.555555556
                },
                "nombre": "Estoy tan cansado que soy incapaz de hacer nada.",
                "pregunta": 11
            },
            {
                "id": 36,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "color": "A",
                    "valor": 2.777777778
                },
                "nombre": "Siento que mi rendimiento ha disminuido algo sin motivo aparente.",
                "pregunta": 11
            }
        ],
        "nombre": "Respecto a mi capacidad de trabajo y energía",
        "test": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "opcion_set": [
            {
                "id": 37,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "color": "R",
                    "valor": 5.555555556
                },
                "nombre": "Han desaparecido pues no tengo deseo sexual.",
                "pregunta": 12
            },
            {
                "id": 38,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "color": "V",
                    "valor": 0.0
                },
                "nombre": "No presentan variación alguna y si la presenta es porque ha existido algún cambio en la posibilidad",
                "pregunta": 12
            },
            {
                "id": 39,
                "tipo_opcion": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "color": "A",
                    "valor": 2.777777778
                },
                "nombre": "Han disminuido de forma notable sin que hayan existido cambios (por ejemplo, ausencia de pareja).",
                "pregunta": 12
            }
        ],
        "nombre": "Mis relaciones sexuales",
        "test": 1
    }
],
"nombre": "Test de Depresión",
"descripcion": "Cuestionario para diagnosticar depresión",
"tipo": "Depresión",
"url_imagen": "https://statics-cuidateplus.marca.com/sites/default/files/depresion_1_0.jpg"
```

**Class PreguntaProvider**

```
class PreguntaProvider with ChangeNotifier{

  final dominio = 'http://192.168.0.2:8000';

  PreguntaProvider(){
    this.fetchPreguntas();
    this.fetchTestList();
  }


  List<Pregunta> _preguntas = [];

  List<Pregunta> get preguntas{
    return [..._preguntas];
  }

  Future <List<Pregunta>> fetchPreguntas() async {

    final url = dominio + '/chatbotapp/test-detail/1/?format=json';
    final response = await http.get(url);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      var dataPreguntas = data["pregunta_set"] as List;
      _preguntas = dataPreguntas.map<Pregunta>((json) => Pregunta.fromJson(json)).toList();
    }
    return _preguntas;
  }
```

**Model Pregunta**

```
class Pregunta{
  final String id;
  final String nombre;
  final List<Opcion> opciones;

  Pregunta({this.id, this.nombre, this.opciones});

  factory Pregunta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List data = json["opcion_set"] as List;
    //data.map<Opcion>((json) => Opcion.fromJson(json)).toList();

    return Pregunta(
      id: json['id'].toString(),
      nombre: json['nombre'],
      opciones: data.map<Opcion>((json) => Opcion.fromJson(json)).toList()
    );
  }

  
}
```

**Model Opcion**

```
class Opcion{
  final int id;
  final int pregunta;
  final String nombre;

  Opcion({this.id, this.pregunta, this.nombre});

  factory Opcion.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Opcion(
      id: json['id'],
      pregunta: json['pregunta'],
      nombre: json['nombre']

    );

  }

}
```

**Class HomePage**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final preguntaP = Provider.of<PreguntaProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Pregunta>>(
        future: preguntaP.fetchPreguntas(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Pregunta>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData){
            return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(snapshot.data[index].nombre),
                subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].opciones.toString()),
                
              );
              
            }
          );
          } else{
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            //return Container();
          }
          
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Esto es lo que muestra en emulador:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad, si logras pintar tus objetos del tipo `Opcion` , el tema es que como no has sobreescrito el método `toString`, solo te pinta el valor por defecto de las instancias.

Podrías hacer algo así :

```dart
class Opcion{
  final int id;
  final int pregunta;
  final String nombre;

  Opcion({this.id, this.pregunta, this.nombre});

  factory Opcion.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Opcion(
      id: json['id'],
      pregunta: json['pregunta'],
      nombre: json['nombre']

    );
  }
 
  @override
  String toString(){
     //aquí define lo que quieres mostrar de tu instancia, por ejemplo: nombre.
     return nombre; 
   }

}
```

Con eso ya pintaría el listado de nombres.